# Lambda in lambda, capture this

Tags: c++, boost, lambda

I have lambda in lambda, and i have a problem with capture this. Is there some option to solve this problem ? Maybe some kind of alias for this ?

```
auto late_connect = wakeup_signal_notify_to_connect.connect([this]()
{
    auto wakeup = wakeup_signal_ptr->connect([this]()
    {
        //here I want to have this from level up
    });
});
```

I try use alias to this:

```
auto late_connect = wakeup_signal_notify_to_connect.connect([this]()
{
    auto* alias_to_this = this;

    this->OnInvokeUpdate(); //here I can obtain thread local storage from boost

    auto wakeup = wakeup_signal_ptr->connect([alias_to_this]()
    {
            alias_to_this->OnInvokeUpdate(); //here I cannot obtain thread local storage from boost
        }
    });
});
```

Guys i forget to tell you that i have a problem with tls from boost when I use lambda in lambda.

Comment: What compiler are you using? And what exactly is the problem?

Comment: Please provide a minimal, complete, and verifiable example. That code [looks fine](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/14669b2a4cab1169)

Answer (score 0):

This should solve your problem:

```
auto late_connect = wakeup_signal_notify_to_connect.connect([this]()
{
    auto that = this;
    auto wakeup = wakeup_signal_ptr->connect([that]()
    {
        //your stuff
    });
});
```

**EDIT**: I thought this through and my solution is pointless. `This` captured by inner lambda is still the same `this` from level up, thus you don't have to make an alias like you would, for example, in a JavaScript's function. Remember, that lambdas only have access to scope where they are defined, not from where they are being invoked. If this was not your issue, please provide more information.

Comment: Why does it solve the problem? Why exactly did the OP's code fail?

Comment: Thanks Piotrek for your answer, I updated my question.